# how can i connect with different SFTP server dynamically?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

i am using spring integration to move a file from SFTP to local directory. i am able to move files from one sftp server to local, i have 3 4 sftp servers, first i thought about writing different classes for each SFTP server, after my research i found that we can use **delegating sessionfactory** for setting more than one SFTP using java. i read the documentation but i couldn't implement that. anybody can help me with that. i am adding my code below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class SftpFileMove {

    @Value("${sftpConfig.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${sftpConfig.username}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${sftpConfig.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${sftpConfig.port}")
    private Integer port;

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        final DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost(host);
        factory.setPort(port);
        factory.setUser(userName);
        factory.setPassword(password);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("/upload/INV/");
        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sftpChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "30000"))
    public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
                sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File("feeds/"));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                BatchProcessorLogger.debug("F111F7B0-9235-11EA-AB12-0800200C9A66", "Moved succussfully to{}",
                        message.getPayload());
            }

        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Inbound Channel Adapters: Polling Multiple Servers and Directories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-rotating-server-advice).

Simply configure a session factory for each server an add them to the delegating factory, each with a key.

Then set up the `RotatingServerAdvice` to cycle through the servers/directories.