# Spring Integration - dynamic multible sftp/ftp sessions with different folders

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration, sftp

i'm not quite sure if spring integration is the right toolset for me.

I would like to enter connection data (SFTP/FTP) into a database and use it time scheduled to fetch data.

But I have several problems now,

1. can I dynamically add SFTP /FTP jobs at spring integration?
2. can I cluster spring integration jobs?

I have found several solutions to have multiple SFTP polls, but they don't work.
For example: [spring integration : solutions/tips on connect multiple sftp server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721822/spring-integration-solutions-tips-on-connect-multiple-sftp-server)

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using Spring Integration Java DSL dynamic flows: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows

So:

1. you do a JDBC Inbound Channel Adapter to poll settings from the database: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-inbound-channel-adapter
2. You create dynamic flows using a `IntegrationFlowContext` populate SFTP server connection factory and remote directory into a SFTP Inbound Channel Adapter and start that dynamic flow: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-inbound

Another option is to consider to use a `RotatingServerAdvice`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-rotating-server-advice

To make such a solution robust in the cluster you should use `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` configured with shared `MetadataStore`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#metadata-store.

This sample demonstrate a technique how to use dynamic flows for TCP/IP, but principle is the same: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client.

Also see this SO thread: [how can i connect with different SFTP server dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62256451/how-can-i-connect-with-different-sftp-server-dynamically)